# Faraday's law question: wire falling over two rails

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, induction

I'm having trouble with this problem. The picture shows a wire of mass m and length l which slides on two rails, with certain angle with respect to the horizontal.The whole circuit has a resistance R and there is a B field which points upwards. I'm asked to find B so that the wire falls at a constant speed. (If you know spanish, you'll get a better undertanding of the situation. I'm not so good at technical english :D)

[image]
So here's what I did:

- From simple mechanics, we have that the force on the wire, parallel to the rail is $F=mg\sin{\alpha}$.
- The flux of B through the surface of the circuit is $\phi =\int \vec B \vec ds $, and the induced EMF is $\varepsilon =-\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=Bgl\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}.t$, and by Ohm's law is also $\varepsilon =iR$, so $i=\frac{Bgl}R \sin {\alpha}\cos{\alpha}.t$
- The magnetic force on the wire is $\vec {F_m}=\int i\vec{dl}\times  \vec{B}=\frac{B^2l^2}R g \sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}.t$
  So $F$ must be the same as $F_m$ for speed to be constant. Then $B=\sqrt{\frac{mR}{l^2\cos{\alpha}.t}}$. Here's the thing, this gives a time-depending $\vec B$, but in step 2 I supossed B was constant, so I don't know what's wrong, any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think you should re-examine your expression for $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} $. Might it be that it is not a function of time?

Comment: It must be that. But the force due to the 'plane', $F=mg\sin{\alpha}$, gives me an acceleration on the horizontal axis, of $a_x=g\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}$, so the surface $\vec B$ goes through is $s(t)=l.a_xt^2/2=lg\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}t^2/2$, and $\phi=\int \vec B \vec {ds}=Bs(t)$. Then $|\varepsilon|=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}=Blg\sin{\alpha}\cos{\alpha}.t$. I don't know where I went wrong!

Comment: I was wrong, in the original post I said $F$ should be equal to $F_m$, but the latter acts on the axis which is parallel to the rails. I have to decompose it and its parallel-to-floor component has to be the same as $F$. But anyway, I'm wrong... I  can't get  it right.

Answer (score -1):

$\frac{dV}{dt}=0$

Hence, $mg\sin\alpha=BIl\cos\alpha$

$I=\frac{mg\tan\alpha}{Bl}\to I=\frac{BVl\cos\alpha}{R}$

$V=\frac{mgR\sin\alpha}{B^2l^2\cos^2\alpha}$

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please use mathjax to format mathematical expressions. To learn more about mathjax, please read [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: This is wrong. I don't have much to say about the first two lines. I didn't read what the given situation was, so whether or not the potential difference is constant I don't care. But you wrote in line 2 that the force is $BIl\cos\alpha$, not the current. You can't later insist that the current is equal to this and then swap the $I$ in the RHS for $\frac{V}{R}$. $I=I$, $I\ne (Bl\cos\alpha)I$, which means you cannot merge them into line 4. In fact, you used $BIl\cos\alpha$ to find $I$. You can't just isolate for $I$ from that and then call the whole thing equal to $I$ again.